# Switch Statement running more than once

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm back again, just as stumped as ever... I have gotten further with my game, but looking back at one part of the game, I have a check to see if you have potions, and if you do, and you try to use it, it calculates whether the current health and the added amount from the potion is more than the max health of the player. If it is then it tells you you cannot drink it, and if it isn't, then it lets you drink it. And then if you don't have any potions and you try to use it, then it tells you you don't have any.

The part I am having issue with, is that it is running twice, and I am not sure why. Here is a snippet of the Switch Statement:

```
while (currentarea == "Hero's Turn") {
    if (hTurn == true) {
        switch (classType) {
            case "Warrior":
            case "Archer":
                switch (input) {
                    case "punch":
                    case "p":
                        Punch();
                        break;
                    case "kick":
                    case "k":
                        Kick();
                        break;
                    case "attack":
                    case "a":
                        Attack();
                        break;
                    case "health potion":
                    case "h":
                        HealthPotion();
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            case "Mage":
                switch (input) {
                    case "fire":
                    case "f":
                        FireMagic();
                        break;
                    case "wind":
                    case "w":
                        WindMagic();
                        break;
                    case "frost":
                    case "c":
                        IceMagic();
                        break;
                    case "health potion":
                    case "h":
                        HealthPotion();
                        break;
                    case "mana potion":
                    case "m":
                        ManaPotion();
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            default:
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I tried to move the Archer to its own line and that just made it run three times. The issue is with the Warrior and Archer, the Mage only pushes the info once as intended.

This is the code for the function:

```
function HealthPotion() {
    if (healthPotion.AmountOf < 1) {
        $("<p>Sorry, you don't have any more of those.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        checkH();
        return;
    }
    if (healthPotion.AmountOf != 0) {
        if(battleHealth + healthPotion.Health <= maxHealth) {
            $("<p>You regained some Health! You regained " + healthPotion.Health + " HP!</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            battleHealth += healthPotion.Health;
            document.getElementById("battleHealth").innerHTML = battleHealth;
            healthPotion.AmountOf--;
            document.getElementById("healthPotion.AmountOf").innerHTML = healthPotion.AmountOf;
            checkE();
            return;
        }
        else {
            $("<p>Your health isn't damaged enough for that! It would be a waste to use that right now.<br />Press enter to carry on.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            checkH();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I have the potion constructed:

```
var healthPotion = { //Recovers battle HP.
   Name: "Health Potion",
   Health: 20,
   AmountOf: 5,
   Value: 30,
}
```

This is where the loops go to (the enemy and the hero check):

```
function checkE() {
    if (eHealth >= 1) {
        currentarea = "Enemy's Turn";
        document.getElementById("currentarea").innerHTML = currentarea;
        hTurn = false;
        eTurn = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (eHealth <= 0) {
        eHealth = 0;
        document.getElementById("eHealth").innerHTML = eHealth;
        currentarea = "Death";
        win++;
        document.getElementById("win").innerHTML = win;
        hTurn = false;
        eTurn = false;
        return;
    }
}
function checkH() {
    if (battleHealth >= 1) {
        currentarea = "Battle";
        document.getElementById("currentarea").innerHTML = currentarea;
        eTurn = false;
        hTurn = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (battleHealth <= 0) {
        battleHealth = 0;
        document.getElementById("battleHealth").innerHTML = battleHealth;
        currentarea = "Death";
        document.getElementById("currentarea").innerHTML = currentarea;
        lose++;
        document.getElementById("lose").innerHTML = lose;
        return;
    }
}
```

At this point I am completely stumped, as I have switch statements and nested functions in all of my coding at this point, but this is the only area I am seeing this issue.
My main browser is Firefox, but I I tested on Chrome and Edge, which both have the same results. IE will not play my game, mainly because I haven't coded it to do so yet.

I looked around at other's questions before posting here, and didn't see anything that matched up to this particular issue.

Looking in the Admin Console of each browser, no error was thrown, just the multiple lines of repeated verbage.

[image: screen shot of the double verbage, playing as a warrior]

If you keep playing and taking damage enough to use the potion, you see this:

[image: screen shot of the double verbage, both using and saying cannot use]

Comment: Do you know how to debug from developer tools?

Comment: Debugging is a critical skill to learn as you learn how to write code. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips. By following these, you will get a deeper understanding of why your code is doing something different than what you expect.

Comment: Your outer `switch` is missing some `break`s

Comment: No, not really. I just know how to use the console to weed out obvious mishaps.

Comment: where are the loop conditions changing?

Comment: @James I did have the breaks in there, but they didn't do anything to remedy the solution, so I just didn't put them back in before pasting the code on here. :/

Comment: Unless the functions you're calling change `currentarea` you have an infiniate loop.

Comment: When posting code here, be careful that you post exactly the same code you are actually using. Also, be sure to post a [mcve] that doesn't cause any errors other than what you are asking about. For example, the code you posted here has a variable named `currentarea` that is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @NinaScholz and At Barmar I updated the code to show the loop as it goes to check the hero or the enemy. At Code-Apprentice The currentarea is defined outside the initial function of the entirety of the game, so I made it a global variable, if my lingo is correct.

Comment: You do not break out of the first switch, only the nested.... so it will go into the next and next....

Comment: btw after `if` with `return`, you need no `else`. just carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You break out of the inner switch, that break does nothing for the outer switch so when you have "Warrior" it does that case and since there is no break at its level, it goes to "Mage"

```
switch (classType) {
  case "Warrior":
  case "Archer":
    switch (input) {
      case "punch":
      case "p":
        Punch();
        break;
      case "kick":
      case "k":
        Kick();
        break;
      case "attack":
      case "a":
        Attack();
        break;
      case "health potion":
      case "h":
        HealthPotion();
        break;
      default:
    }
    break; // <-- YOU NEED THIS HERE
  case "Mage":
    switch (input) {
      case "fire":
      case "f":
        FireMagic();
        break;
      case "wind":
      case "w":
        WindMagic();
        break;
      case "frost":
      case "c":
        IceMagic();
        break;
      case "health potion":
      case "h":
        HealthPotion();
        break;
      case "mana potion":
      case "m":
        ManaPotion();
        break;
      default:
    }
    break; // <-- YOU NEED THIS HERE IF YOU DO SOMETHING IN DEFAULT
  default:
}
```

Comment: Christ... I didn't know I needed a break there. Thank you.
I thought I had other nested switch statements in my code, but I was wrong. So far this is the first one.